# How can I expand the maximum Video Memory?

Tags: windows-8, memory, graphics-card

I just bought GTA V for PC, but I want a better play experience. I am using a laptop: HP Pavilion (Windows 8). Installed RAM is 8gb, but in the game it is limited to only 1gb of video memory (Which is terribly hard to use in that game).

If I am totally wrong and it is my graphics card that I need to upgrade, please tell me. I have a: AMD Radeon (TM) R7 M260. I've been searching around the Internet, but never managed to fix this. I can't understand if I have Installed 8gb and can only use 1gb. Please help.

Comment: You can't.  Your VRAM is limited by your hardware.

Comment: My hardware? So I need to upgrade my hardware? Install a new one?

Comment: You won't be able to upgrade the GPU in your laptop its not a user serviceable part.

Comment: the R7 M260 is slower compared to my over 2 years old Radeon HD 7730M that I have in my laptop. Here you want have any fun to play GTA.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot upgrade the GPU on your laptop as it's soldered to the board. It is set to use 1 GB of to the system RAM. If you check the BIOS, you may be able to increase the amount of RAM that is allocated to the GPU.

Comment: I've checked the BIOS, but I cant edit any amount a RAM

Comment: @Chriss10an - You are out of luck then.